# Externalilze part of the code in Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Is there any way to use Browserify to externalize parts of the code?
The external bundle may have several dependencies in core bundle and should not bundle any of them.

To illustrate the problem, here are the modules.

#### base.js

```
var shared = require('./shared');
var Base = function Base() {};
module.exports = Base;
```

#### base-impl-a.js

```
var shared = require('./shared');
var Base = require('./base');
function BaseA(params) {
    Base.call(this, params);
};
for (var k in Base.prototype)
    BaseA.prototype[k] = Base.prototype[k];
module.exports = BaseA;
```

#### base-impl-b.js

```
var shared = require('./shared');
var Base = require('./base');
function BaseB(params) {
    Base.call(this, params);
};
for (var k in Base.prototype)
    BaseB.prototype[k] = Base.prototype[k];
module.exports = BaseB;
```

#### shared.js

```
module.exports = {};
```

#### main.js

```
shared = require('./shared');
ImplementedBase = require('./base');
```

Ultimately here is how the fines would be used:

#### main-a.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="impl-a-bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="base-bundle.js"></script>
```

#### main-b.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="impl-b-bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="base-bundle.js"></script>
```

I have parts of the solution, but I'm unable to do two things to complete it:

1. Circular dependency handling (though I can probably just externalize common stuff found in core and impl)
2. Simply bundle all specified modules and externalize all other ones (aka not list all of them)